# ios 5: Calling a block in iPhone twice for different values

Tags: ios, geocoding, objective-c-blocks

It may sound weird but I am facing a problem in calling a same block of code twice for different values. When the same code is repeated, I found that the first one only gets executed while second one is not even called. Please help

```
-(void) showRestaurants {
if (!self.geocoder) {
    self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}

            NSArray *web = [detail valueForKeyPath:@"Address"];
            NSLog(@"NO OF VALUES^^^^^^^^^^^^^^:: %@", web);
            int count = [web count];

            NSString *value;

//Other place of interest nearby
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                 value = [web objectAtIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"==> %@", value);
                [self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:value completionHandler:^(NSArray *marks, NSError *failed) {
                    if ([marks count] > 0) {
                        NSLog(@"call Me....");
                        CLPlacemark *placemark = [marks objectAtIndex:0];
                        location = placemark.location;
                        coordinate = location.coordinate;
                        coordinate.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
                        coordinate.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

                        //for first co-ordinate :: SOURCE
                        MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
                        newRegion.center.latitude = coordinate.latitude;
                        newRegion.center.longitude = coordinate.longitude;
                        newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.029321;
                        newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.034589;

                        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                        [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
                        //AppDelegate *dataCenter = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                        [annotation setTitle:value];
                        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
                        [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

                    }
                }];
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with blocks. Your blocks stuff looks fine. However, if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/geocodeAddressString%3acompletionHandler%3a) of the geocoding method you're using, it says

> After initiating a forward-geocoding request, do not attempt to
>   initiate another forward- or reverse-geocoding request.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My bad, I did not notice it. I tried hard coding the coordinates in the database and have annotations based on those values but the following assignment shows compile time error:
newRegion.center.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[detail valueForKeyPath:@"Address"] objectAtIndex:0]];